# Are VM snapshots enough to backup SQL?

Tags: sql-server, azure

I have a Microsoft SQL DB running on Azure VM

I have daily snapshots of the VM and this is currently my only backup mechanism.

Is this considered best practice? Am I risking something here?

Comment: Are you willing to lose 24 hours of transactions if the database crashes 23 hours 59 minutes after the last VM snapshot?

Answer (score 3):

Before I tell you if you following best practice or no, I suggest you understand few terms which dictates what kind of backup plan is suitable for you. This will also enable you to decide if you are risking something or no.

**Recovery models**

> There are three recovery models:
>
> **Full recovery model (the default and the most commonly used)** All modifications in the database a fully logged The log will not clear
> until a transaction log backup is performed
>
> **Bulk-logged recovery model** Some modifications (like an index rebuild or a bulk load) can be minimally logged, which reduces the
> amount of log records generated The log will not clear until a
> transaction log backup is performed, just like the full recovery model
>
> **Simple recovery model** Some modifications can be minimally logged, just like the bulk-logged recovery model The log will not clear until
> a checkpoint occurs (usually automatically), and transaction log
> backups are not possible

**Backup types**

> There are three commonly used backup types in SQL Server:
>
> Full database backup
>
> Transaction log backup
>
> Differential database backup

**RTO stands for Recovery Time Objective.**

> In simple terms, you can think of RTO as a measure of how much downtime is acceptable, or how
> quickly must the data be made accessible again. RTO is often talked
> about in terms of the number of nines of desirable up time or
> accessibility for the data/database/system. For example, 5-nines means
> 99.999% up-time, and if that’s being measured 24 hours a day, 365 days a year, then that translates into just over 5 minutes of allowable
> downtime per year. That’s really hard to achieve. It’s easier to meet
> 4-nines (52.5 minutes per year of downtime) or 3-nines (8.75 hours per
> year of downtime).
>
> When discussing the desired up time, you have to decide whether it’s
> being measured 24×365, or 9am-5pm during weekdays, or some other time
> period. You also need to decide whether the measured downtime includes
> scheduled downtime for maintenance/patching or not, as it’s much
> easier to meet a high number of nines if scheduled maintenance is
> permitted.

**RPO stands for Recovery Point Objective.**

> In simple terms, you can think of RPO as a measure of how much data or work it’s
> acceptable to lose. It’s relatively easy to achieve very minimal or
> even zero data/work loss using backups, but depending on the amount of
> damage the database suffered when the disaster hit, recovering might
> take a lot of time. For instance, if an entire database is destroyed,
> depending on the architecture of the database and the backups that
> exist, it may take a significant amount of time to recover the
> database up to the point of the disaster. Most RPOs are defined as the
> the amount of time for which work may be lost. For example, an RPO
> might be that the database should be recoverable to a point within
> thirty minutes of the disaster occurring, which means that up to 30
> minutes of work may be lost.

Once you understand the above concept then you need to make a backup strategy. Make sure your business counter-part is in agreement with your strategy, especially about how much data you can lose. Read the article I listed in reference about planning a recovery strategy.

Reference:

1. [The Accidental DBA (Day 7 of 30): Backups: Recovery Models and Backup Types](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/the-accidental-dba-day-7-of-30-backups-recovery-models-and-backup-types/) by Paul Randal
2. [Database Maintenance Best Practices Part III – Transaction Log Maintenance](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/database-maintenance-best-practices-part-iii-transaction-log-maintenance/) by Kimberly Tripp
3. [The Accidental DBA (Day 8 of 30): Backups: Planning a Recovery Strategy](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/the-accidental-dba-day-8-of-30-backups-planning-a-recovery-strategy/) by Paul Randal
4. [The Accidental DBA (Day 6 of 30): Backups: Understanding RTO and RPO](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/the-accidental-dba-day-6-of-30-backups-understanding-rto-and-rpo/) by Paul Randal